# R - Factor-to-Numeric Conversion using pattern matching

Tags: r, dataframe, r-factor

I have seen many questions on here addressing the issue of converting factors to numeric variables but none seem to address what I am trying to do.

I want to create a new column in a dataframe that contains numeric representations of an existing factor. I tried:

```
df$num = as.numeric(df$factor)
```

Which converted the factors but did not order them as needed. How can I define each factor's numeric value explicitly? Something along the lines of:

```
df$num = ("1" if factor == "GB", "2" if factor == "YT", "3" if factor == "BF")
```

Comment: If you want to make specify a numeric value you should get rid of the quotes around 1,2 and 3.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [levels](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/levels.html) or [gl](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/gl.html)?

Comment: A reproducible example would be delightful.

Comment: consider the following, `f <- factor(letters); as.integer(f); f <- factor(f, levels=rev(letters)); as.integer(f)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a factor variable `num` with 3 levels (`GB`, `YT`, `BF`) that you want to analyze as numeric.

I solved a similar problem by converting to character first, ex:

```
df$num <- as.character(df$num)
```

Then recoding to numeric values

```
df$num <- recode(df$num, "GB" = 1, "YT" = 2, "BF" = 3)
```

It's not elegant, but this strategy worked for my similar problem.